# How to use custom theme font family in tailwind css?

Tags: css, fonts, tailwind-css, font-face

I am creating a static website using tailwind and I tried to create a custom font family but not working.

Here is my project structure just in case:

```
my-project/
├── dist/
├── node_modules/
├── src/
│   ├── font/
│   │   └── Monospace.ttf
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── input.css
│   └── output.css
├── .nojekyll
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── README.md
└── tailwind.config.js
```

Here is my tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,js}",
    "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      theme: {
        fontFamily: {
          display: ['IBM Plex Mono', 'Menlo', 'monospace'],
          body: ['IBM Plex Mono', 'Menlo', 'monospace'],
          monospace: ['Monospace2'],
        },
        colors: {
          primary: {
            50: '#f9fafb',
            100: '#f3f4f6',
            200: '#e5e7eb',
            300: '#d1d5db',
            400: '#9ca3af',
            500: '#6b7280',
            600: '#4b5563',
            700: '#374151',
            800: '#1f2937',
            900: '#111827',
          },
          secondary: {
            50: '#f0fdfa',
            100: '#ccfbf1',
            200: '#99f6e4',
            300: '#5eead4',
            400: '#2dd4bf',
            500: '#14b8a6',
            600: '#0d9488',
            700: '#0f766e',
            800: '#115e59',
            900: '#134e4a',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin'),
  ],
}
```

The ones not working is the display, body, and monospace font family

```
        fontFamily: {
          display: ['IBM Plex Mono', 'Menlo', 'monospace'],
          body: ['IBM Plex Mono', 'Menlo', 'monospace'],
          monospace: ['Monospace2'],
        },
```

and here is my input.css (I tried to use custom font from .tff instead for the monospace font-family)

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@font-face {
    font-family: "Monospace2";
    src: url("font/Monospace.ttf");
}
```

I use the command `tailwindcss -i src/input.css -o src/output.css --watch` on watch so the output.css is updated regularly. Here in my output.css I found the Monospace2 font but I can't find the .font-monospace I created customly:

```
@font-face{font-family:"Monospace2";src:url(font/Monospace.ttf)}
```

the .font-display, .font-body, and .font-monospace or font-Monospace2 class are not found so I thought I need to import the font myself (my attempt with the Monospace2 font-family) but I only found the @font-face, in my index html I tried this:

```
<p class="font-monospace">This is your section content.</p>
<p class="font-Monospace2">This is your section content.</p>
```

it doesn't work, while if style it manually it works fine:

```
<style>
    .font-Monospace2 {
        font-family: Monospace2;
    }
</style>
<p class="font-Monospace2">This is your section content.</p>
```

I also found in network that the Monospace.tff is loaded properly while if I don't do it manually it doesn't, do I miss something? still learning tailwind css, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

declare the font face in global.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Monospace';
    src: url('font/Monospace.ttf) format('ttf'),
}
```

then in tailwind config

```
 fontFamily: {
      'monospace': ['Monospace', ...],
      ...other fonts
    }
```

usage

```
class="font-monospace"
```

Comment: there is no global.css, I use input.css maybe I should include the project structure, and I did that font-face in the input.css

Comment: okay so mostly there should be global.css if not \the file where you have initialized the tailwind you have to declare the font face there and it should work

Comment: from the tailwind installation documentation I use the tailwind CLI tool

Comment: okay from the edits you have made, I am thinking that that is happening because you have added number in the name (It counts as a string then to). I have never used this way i may recommend you to try remove 2 and run it make sure once you have made the changes re-run the code

Comment: i did before it with the name only "monospace" it is just my other attempts become "Monospace2", it actually work fine if i just declare the css in input.css like .monospace {} but i thought tailwind will generate it for me if i declare it in tailwind config.